# Why does 'coed' only mean female coeducational students?

Tags: etymology, american-english

As an adjective, the word [coed](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/co-ed#Adjective), short for coeducational, indicates an institution that teaches both males and females. However, [as a noun](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/co-ed#Noun), it can only mean "a young **woman** who attends college". Why is this so and how did this come about?

Comment: http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=co-ed

Comment: It's a result of the history of education in the U.S. Early students were all male. When women were allowed, the term _co-education_ was introduced, and women were called _co-eds_.

Comment: @MετάEd Thanks. It doesn't really explain how or why though ...

Comment: Never underestimate the power of sexism in etymology.

Comment: @JohnLawler Thanks. That sounds odd, but plausible. Is this general opinion? There appear to have been [coeducational and women's colleges in the US](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Women's_colleges_in_the_United_States) long before 1893.

Comment: @coleopterist It's certainly the explanation I would have given had you asked me on the spot and I had no time to research. While I can't speak to the actual origin the mild sexism angle would be the assumption today.

Comment: @coleopterist Actually that reference does pretty well explain the origin of the term. "Co-eds" was coined when people lacked a word specifically for women attending newly coeducational schools. If "Co-eds" hadn't caught on, something equally condescending would have been adopted, perhaps "co-students" or "pupilettes". Another choice term I've seen is "college girls".

Comment: @MετάEd To me, all that the reference states is the year of first use. The rest, while highly possible, appears to be conjecture. [This page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed-sex_education) provides a list of colleges along with the dates they became co-ed; while the American University became co-ed in 1893, there had been other such institutions as far back as 1833 including Cornell and UPenn. The late 1800s also appears to have seen the introduction of the system of "coordinate colleges".

Comment: Incidentally, according to [Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/coed), first known use = ~1878, eight years prior to _Jo's Boys_.

Comment: I don't think it's so much that "early students were all male" but that "early colleges were single sex."  I suspect it is because the idea of a woman playing a man's role is so much more jarring than the reverse, from a sexist point of view, that a "co-ed" is a woman going to a mixed-sex college rather than a "co-ed" being a woman *or man* going to a mixed-sex college.

Comment: @Merk You are correct: co-education meant women were suddenly welcome in men's schools. I don't know, but I think, women's schools mostly did not open to men until quite a bit later on.

Comment: @Souta Please keep the tone polite and respectful.

Comment: @Souta Please reconsider "blind" and "if you had bothered". If you agree, then deleting and reposting your comments would be welcome. For your consideration, the site offers guidelines on [etiquette](http://english.stackexchange.com/faq#etiquette) as well as the purpose of [comments](http://english.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: Dates given in etymological dictionaries are never intended to be taken as, nor should they ever be taken as, the very absolute earliest dates the word was ever uttered. They are merely the earliest dates for which the author of the etymological dictionary has found the term published in an authoritative source.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Cornell University, one of the first universities to embrace coeducation, [became a coed institution in 1870](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed-sex_education). In a 2005 book by Margaret A. Lowe titled [Looking Good: College Women and Body Image, 1875-1930](http://books.google.com/books?id=9YQiDjNTQnoC), the author explains using first-hand accounts by the pioneering "coeds" of the time:

> But once intertwined with feminist politics (whether embraced or disavowed on campus), coeducation further threatened Cornell's decision to admit women. The feminist link painted female students with the derogatory brush of unladylike desire. Considered strident intruders, they took the heat for destabilizing gender categories—it was they who crossed into male space and therefore put their moral authority in doubt. **Female students would be called "coeds"**; the term **"student" referred solely to men**. One early Cornellian recalled, "We were called 'co-eds'...and we should have been much more touchy than we were to mind it." In a humorous column for the *Cornell Era*, another student recalled that on her first day in Ithaca, "a boarding house keeper, of British birth, asked me if I were a a 'co-hed.'...'Co-head'!...But the attitude of our British friend was not so far remote from that of out student brother; to both a coed (A co-head) is an anomaly, a monstrosity."

In other words, the males were called *students* while the females were not; they were instead called *coeds*. So, the sexism theory prevails.

Webster's [estimated date of first use](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/coed)—1878—is in keeping with the above excerpt. [Etymonline's estimate is off](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=co-ed) by a couple of decades. There are a few other sources that also cover this topic; but all they do is parrot the (correct) dictionary definition rather than provide any real insight into the why and how of the question.

Comment: That's a historical account of how some students responded to the term, not a etymological account of how the term originated or why. 

The process of how and why the term originated falls under what etymologists call metonymy. Determining whether the driving force behind the process was some deep-seated collective ill-will toward the entire female gender, or a simple desire for a shorter word than "female student" and the fact that "coed" is catchy would require a hell of a lot more justification.

Comment: Identifying gender was only important whenever speaking about female students, as if something else should be expected from them.  That is the very definition of sexism. It may be useful to note that sexism, though harmful, is not  always rooted in a "deep-seated collective ill-will".  In this case, it was likely the traditional association between womanhood, femininity, lower IQs, and subservience, but for many (perhaps most) people of that era such views were commonplace based in pure ignorance (not mean-spirited in nature) though, no doubt, some men felt threatened and reacted accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

The process is called [metonymy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metonymy), calling the members of a set something associated with that set. A student of a type of educational system is called by the name of the system.

But this doesn't explain why only females are called by this term. Even though logically both males and females in a co-educational environment could be called 'co-eds', only females were. At the time of adoption of this word (the late 19th c), most colleges were predominately male, and for the college to become 'co-educational' the newer students who were also much fewer in number, were the females. Since the newer set is the exceptional case, the metonymy only applied to the marked case, the females.

Comment: Again, this appears to be conjecture. While it seems logical, I'm unsure what everybody is basing this theory on. Having read John Lawler's and @Merk 's comments, I can extrapolate even further: Women in the 1800s used to attend women's colleges. However, once men's colleges became coed, some women, rather than attending pristine and pure women's colleges, chose to lower themselves by attending coed institutions thereby being branded _coeds_. Thus, coeds was initially a derogatory term rather than a sexist one. | To me, this theory is just as, if not more convincing than the others.

Comment: @coleopterist: OK, but then what would be a convincing answer to a 'why' question? Are you looking for the explicit explanation by the person who very first used it in speech? Sometimes that is available but not often. If you can't come up with good criteria or there is no way to fulfill the criteria, then this might not be a constructive question. As to derogatory, 'coed' is unlikely to be such, rather it sounds more like a euphemism to replace harsher words that a boys club might use (I have no evidence, but I'm just trying to pursue the conjectural possibility that you suggest).

Comment: Surely I'm not the first person to ask this question. There must be feminists galore who have looked into this. I don't think that the story is that obvious that the answer is plain as day. Usually such theories have their origins in some written work. A more reliable source than according-to-this-chap-on-the-net will be nice :)

Comment: @MarcelTuring: the law of logic is called the law of implication through definition. A 'co-educational' school means teaching both sexes in the same classes. Note that no sex is preferred in that terminology. So how come _logically and literally_ is co-ed to be preferred for females over males? I gave an extra-logical explanation. So, to you, what is a logical explanation for preferring one sex over the other?

Comment: Metonymy only applies when the new subset is perceived as being significantly different.  Otherwise they would all simply be called "students", no need to label them differently.

Answer (score 1):

The formal explanation:
"The process is called metonymy, calling the members of a set something associated with that set. A student of a type of educational system is called by the name of the system." makes a lot of sense.

... as in atheletes: jocks, drive-in waitresses: car-hops, contract workers: temps, prisoners: cons, US soldiers: GIs, adolescents: teens, etc.

It is of no significance that the use of the word "coed" to identify a woman was at times defamatory, hip, sexy, or neutral. What is stated here is a verifiable answer for how female students came to be called coeds.

Answer (score 0):

In this context, men were "educated" and women were "CO-educated." That is, they were educated "alongside" men, not really in their own right.

Answer (score 0):

The addition of female students to formerly all-male schools made the schools *coeducational*. The female students were thus referred to by the incumbent male population as *coeds*, because it was the female students' enrollment that made a school *coeducational*.